# Insert Result of an Internal Vim Command into Text/Buffer (e.g. vims echo command)

Tags: vimscript, external-command, command, expression-register

### Question

I want to have basically the same as `:read ![external command]`, but instead the **external command** I want to read the output from an **internal command**.

### Example

**Shells echo / external command:**
`:read !echo 0x539` -> `output: 0x539`

**Vims echo / internal command:**
`:read echo 0x539` -> `output: 1337`

---

### More explanation

The second example will obviously fail, because thats not vim syntax. But is there an equivalent how I can archive this in vim/neovim? I know that you can generally output the result from vimscript commands in the `"=` register. (In case you don't know, you can press `CTRL-R` and then `=` **while being in insert mode** to get into the expression register). But I don't know how to use `echo` with it.

So if you have any ideas, I would be glad to hear them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One version:

```
:put =execute('echo 0x539')
```

though I would probably do `i<C-v>u0539<esc>`.

You can also `redir => {var}` into a variable, which can be more readable than the `execute()` function (different from the command!) if there are multiple lines of script.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I wanted. And I know I could use `i<CTRL-V>...` but I have a lot of hex numbers and I think to use the vim-echo command is the best way to convert them all. I just took 0x539 just as an example, but still thanks :) And btw you can use `<CTRL-R>=execute('echo abc')` (in **insert mode**) too :))

Comment: You can maybe use something like `:%s/0x[a-fA-F0-9]\+/\=submatch(0)->str2nr(16)/` @Pixelbog; that finds all hex numbers starting with `0x` and replaced it with the decimal variant.

Comment: oh wow thank you very much. I learned 3 new things from you :) `1.` the submatch(0) thing. `2.` the whole line, really interesting what you can all do in vim. Vim is really beautiful isnt it? :) And `3.` for some reason if I try to use the exact same line in **neovim**, it does not work. So I have now more to learn :D Thank you very much :))

Comment: @Pixelbog yes I'm aware of `i_CTRL-R`. For brevity I would be inclined to use the pattern `0x\x\+`.

Comment: Oh wow thats so cool :D I learned something new again. I didn't know that there is an hexadecimal escape, thanks :))

Answer (score 2):

> But I don't know how to use echo with it.

You don't.

What comes after `:help :echo` is an *expression* but `:echo <expr>` is not the only way to consume expressions. As it stands, the `"=` register that you use with `:help i_ctrl-r` is called "expression register" for a reason: it expects an *expression*, like `:echo`.

`0x0539` is the expression you want to consume so, in insert mode, `<C-r>=0x0539<CR>` inserts `1337` at the cursor, as expected.

Comment: First of all, dude I see you almost all over the internet, if it has to do something with vim xD I love it haha. And second, maybe it is a stupid question, but do you know if I can write multiple hex numbers seperated by a comma or in an array?

Comment: Nevermind. I should have first tested it before writing a comment haha. The **Answer** is yes it is possible, in array of strings seperated by commas. Like this: `=['0x539', '0x45', '0x2a']` :)

Comment: @Pixelbog a list of numbers should work, but the expression register typically turns lists into multiple lines.