# Neovim E276 - Command works in Vim but Not in Neovim

Tags: neovim, command-line, command

### Question

Thanks to the [comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/39369/insert-result-of-an-internal-vim-command-into-text-buffer-e-g-vims-echo-comman/39370?noredirect=1#comment72060_39370) from [@martin-tournoij](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/51/martin-tournoij) on one of my other questions. He gave me this piece of code:

`:%s/0x[a-fA-F0-9]\+/\=submatch(0)->str2nr(16)/`

which looks for every **hex-number** like `0x10` or `0x539` and replaces it with the corresponding decimal value.

Okay now why this code only works in **vim** and not in **neovim**. Neovim throws this error:

`E276: Cannot use function as method: str2nr`

---

So **Why??** Where is the problem??

Comment: I am not sure if someone can answer this, but I will give it a try ^^

Comment: Something like `:%s/0x[a-fA-F0-9]\+/\=str2nr(submatch(0), 16)/` should probably work, but I don't have Neovim installed so I can't test. I think Neovim ported methods from Vim only very recently.

Comment: Also: you can use `:help <error-code>`: [`:help E267`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/eval.html#E276), and that often gives you more detail on the error message. `str2nr()` [is documented as supporting the method call syntax](https://neovim.io/doc/user/builtin.html#str2nr()), so either you've got an older Neovim version which doesn't support it yet, or it's a bug in Neovim

Comment: It works, thanks :)) Wow I started to be on vi/vim exchange only like 2 weeks ago, and I have learned an incredible amount of things^^ Also funny enough, the **Error Code** `E276` doesn't exist in **neovim**, only in **vim** ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VimScript the function composition can be written in two ways, either "traditional" `g(f(x))`, or "method" notation `f(x)->g()`.

However, the latter one must be defined by VimScript engine for every function particularly (that's because some functions need argument other than the first one). So availability of method notation for a particular function depends on Vim/Neovim version/patch number.

And for Neovim it could be a real pain, as it both lags behind Vim and gets updated in some major repos quite infrequently.

So if you ever encounter this error then rewrite your code using more traditional syntax for function calls.